# Euclidean algorithm and its formal proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose that $a,b\in \mathbb{N}$ and our goal to find $\text{gcd}(a,b)$ and the most effective way to do that is the Euclidean algorithm. I know how the algorithm works but I'd like to understand thoroughly and that is why I created this topic because some moments are not crystal clear to me.

Suppose we are given two natural numbers $a,b\in \mathbb{N}$ and assume that $a>b$ with $a\nmid b$.

**Step #0.** Then there is the unique pair of integers $q_0, r_2$ such that $a=bq_0+r_2,$ where $0<r_2<b$. Let's introduce the new notation $r_0:=a$ and $r_1:=b$. Then

$$r_0=r_1q_0+r_2, \text{where} \ 0<r_2<r_1.$$

**Step #1.** Then we apply the same procedure to the pair $\{r_1,r_2\}$ and obtain that

$$r_1=r_2q_1+r_3, \text{where} \ 0\leq r_3<r_2.$$

If $r_3=0$ then $(a,b)=r_2$ and I know how to prove it.

If $r_3>0$ then we move on to the **Step #2** where $r_2=r_3q_2+r_4$ with $0\leq r_4<r_3$.

**Claim:** On some **step #m** with $m\geq 1$ the remainder $r_{m+2}$ will vanish.

*Proof:* Suppose this is false. Then on any **step #m** the remained is nonzero, i.e. $r_{m+2}>0$. Then it is easy to show that $r_{n+2}\leq b-n-1$. Hence $0<r_{b+2}\leq -1<0$. But this is a contradiction.

Hence $\exists m\geq 1$ such that $r_{m+2}=0$. Then it implies that $r_{m+1}\neq 0$ (otherwise if $r_{m+1}=0$ then $r_m=\dots=r_1=0$, right? Can anyone show the rigorous proof of that? Probably the proof relies on induction).

Hence $r_{m+1}\mid r_m$ and $(a,b)=(b,r_2)=(r_1,r_2)=\dots=(r_m,r_{m+1})=r_{m+1}.$

Is my reasoning correct? If yes, can anyone explain the question which I've asked?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You showed that there exist $m$ such that $r_{m+2} = 0$. Now we can not directly conclude that $r_{m+1} \ne 0$. <s>In fact we can show that there exist $k$ such that $r_k = 0$ but $r_{k-1} \ne 0$. To see this let $ S = \{ t \in \mathbb{N} \, \vert \, r_t = 0 \} $. Clearly $S$ is non emty since $m+2 \in S$. By well ordering principle $S$ has a least element $k$ such that $r_k = 0$. This would imply that $r_{k-1}$ is non zero since $k-1 $ is not in $S$</s> .

But the above argument using well ordering principle isn't really necessary, since  for each $i$, we have  $r_i > r_{i+1}$. S0 $0=r_{m+2}  < r_{m+1} < r_m < \cdots r_1 $. So this gives us that $r_{i} \ne 0$ for all $i =1,2 \dots ,m+1$

**Another approach:**
Alternatively, You have the chain of inequalities $r_1 > r_2 > \cdots $ where each $r_i \ge 0$. Argue that this chain cannot contain infinite number of elements (indeed it can contain at-most $r_1$ elements). Then strict inequality yields one of $r_m=0$

Comment: Sorry but your answer has nothing in common with my question.

Comment: @PlayGame I edited my answer.

Comment: Actually I was also thinking in this manner (through well ordering principle). But there is one subtle moment: If $r_{i}=0$ then the process terminates, i.e. there and $r_j$ with $j>I$. I mean that if $r_{m+2}=0$ then previous terms should be non-zero. If one of the previous terms is zero then the sequence $r_{m+2}$ does not make sense. So we have to be very careful. That is why I am so confused with Euclid algorithm.

Comment: We should use the fact $r_i > r_{i+1}$ for each $i$.

Comment: Please read my comment carefully. If at some $r_i=0$ then there is no $r_{I+1}$ so it is not valid to talk about $r_i>r_{I+1}$ for each $I$.

Comment: I already edited my answer also accordingly, observe that we have $0 = r_{m+2}  < r_{m+1} < r_m < \cdots < r_1$, this would imply that $r_i \ne 0$ for all $i = 1,2, \dots m+1$

Comment: Even after correction your answer has still some issues I guess.  It is not rigorous.

Comment: I do not understand what you meant by "rigorous".  As far as I know in mathematics, it means that using the hypothesis properly to prove something.

Comment: I still cannot get it. Can we discuss it in a chat please?

Comment: Hello! Sorry but can we discuss it in the chat please?

Comment: Yea , we can discuss

Comment: Do you know how to open char for discussion, please?

Comment: Hello! Can we start our discussion please?

Comment: You can join [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/127383/room-to-discuss-the-question-euclidean-algorithm-and-its-formal-proof?tab=general)

Comment: I joined the chat